# How to set font style for extjs emptyText?

Tags: extjs

Would like to set the font style for extjs emptyText to italic rather than normal. This link suggests that style is inherited from com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.BoxComponent but I can't find where.

http://www.sencha.com/helpcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.extjs.gxt.help/html/reference/uml-api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/Field.html

From this same  help topic: The following 4 methods inherited from UIObject (setSize, setWidth, setHeight, setPixelSize) have been overridden and do nothing. Any component whose size can change should subclass BoxComponent.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: You should tag your question with 'ext-gwt'.

Answer (score 1):

You must change the **.x-form-empty-field**.
to do must change the cls to the form.

In the line 14 I change the cls to "newCSS" 
and in the css i add the .x-form-empty-field to newCSS

```
.newCSS .x-form-empty-field{
    font-style : italic;
}
```

this is the fiddle with the changes

http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/ySf52/1/

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

emptyCls might help you with your problem

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-emptyCls